# Regex for string with separate sections

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions in Java and I have to match a pattern of
`[0-9999][A-Z][0-9999][-][0-99]` for an input from the user. I'm not quite sure how to separate the different sections!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex `[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z][0-9]{1,4}[-][0-9]{1,2}`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a String that match [0-9999][A-Z][0-9999][-][0-99]");

    String input = scan.nextLine();

    //If your input match with your String, then print Match, else Not match
    System.out.println(input.matches("[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z][0-9]{1,4}[-][0-9]{1,2}") ? 
            "Match" : "Not Match");
}
```

**Explication**

```
[0-9]{1,4}      # A number between 0 and 9999
[A-Z]           # An alphabetic A to Z
[0-9]{1,4}      # A number between 0 and 9999
[-]             #  - 
[0-9]{1,2}      # A number between 0 and 99
```

Comment: okay that was along the lines of what i was thinking. thank you so much!!

Comment: is that help you or not @MattyD ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use groups in the regex as below.

```
([0-9999])([A-Z])([0-9999])[-]([0-99])
```

Then you'll be able to use [Matcher.group()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) to find groups.

You can see it working here

https://regex101.com/r/hW3O5Z/1

You can read more about it at

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern would look like:

```
 r'[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z][0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}'
```

The square braces define sets so [0-9] will find any number between 0 and 9

The curly braces are quantifiers so {1,4} matches looks for the next 1 to 4 matches of whatever comes before it

To match the dash we just type the character

So this whole regex will look for 1 to 4 characters between 0 and 9 then a character between A and Z then 1 to 4 characters between 0 and 9 then a dash then 1 to 2 characters between 0 and 9